# Remove an existing item from array, when adding the same item

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've created a simple form that display input data below the form, and I want to add 2 functionalities to it:

2. When clicking on any of LI items, that item should be placed at the top of the list.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "", items: [] };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ items: [this.state.value, ...this.state.items] });

    this.setState({ value: "" });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button>submit</button>
        </form>

        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

1. When adding an item that alreday exists, the older version should be removed from the array, so the array doesn't contain duplicated items.

```
// eg. add 1 to [3, 2, 1] => [1, 3, 2]
```

2. When clicking on any of LI items, that item should be placed at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter to remove the value when you set it so it would be like the following:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "", items: [] };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ 
      value:"",
      items: [this.state.value, ...this.state.items.filter(val => val !== this.state.value)] 
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button>submit</button>
        </form>

        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a unique array by merging the current items and the new value like this:

```
    const { value } = this.state;
    const currentItems = [...this.state.items];
    const items = [...new Set([...currentItems, ...value])];
```

You can find a working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5l3v6r3km